# NGINX configuration for the same folder protection rewrites in each of thousands of subdirectories

Tags: security, url-rewriting, nginx, access-control

The following code allows me to protect a specific folder with the membership software we're using. The problem is if we have 1,000 folders we need to protect, we need to copy/paste this same code for each and every folder.

I'm wondering, how can I change the "`location ^~ /FOLDER/`" location so it encompasses every folder with the parent folder we want, and the "`FOLDERID`" so that it encompasses every number? (1 through infinite)

```
location ^~ /FOLDER/ {
        if ($cookie_amember_nr !~* [a-zA-Z0-9]+) { #not authorized
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://EXAMPLE.COM/AMEMBER/protect/new-rewrite?f=FOLDERID&url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
        }
        set $file $document_root/AMEMBER/data/new-rewrite/$cookie_amember_nr-FOLDERID;
        if (!-f $file) { #have not access
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://EXAMPLE.COM/AMEMBER/no-access/folder/id/FOLDERID?url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
        }    
        #everything is ok
    }
```

- FOLDER with actual path to your protected folder
- `http://EXAMPLE.COM/AMEMBER` with your actual aMember installation url
- `/AMEMBER/` with path to aMember installation on your server
- FOLDERID with ID (integer value) for this folder in aMember CP

Example:

```
location ^~ /protect-folders/folder-1/ {
        if ($cookie_amember_nr !~* [a-zA-Z0-9]+) { #not authorized
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://stackexamples.com/amember/protect/new-rewrite?f=513&url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
        }
        set $file $document_root/amember/data/new-rewrite/$cookie_amember_nr-513;
        if (!-f $file) { #have not access
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://stackexamples.com/amember/no-access/folder/id/513?url=$request_uri?$args redirect;
        }    
        #everything is ok
    }
```